# How to get radio button value to int and calculate in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Here is the output of this exercise]I just started to learn Flutter/Dart as my lecturer ask me to do some simple mobile app of e-ticket where the user need to choose from the radio button the movie that have value price for each radio button . Then the user need to input quantity value then click the submit button where the result of calculation need to be shown in another result page. Below is the picture of the assignment and some code that i have done. But i got stuck in the calculation part where i did not find any solution to this. hope anyone can help me with this.

**main dart**
main dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'result.dart';
import 'customer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
enum SingingCharacter { avengers, batman, kimetsu }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final txtName= TextEditingController();
  final txtEmail = TextEditingController();
  final txtQuantity = TextEditingController();
  SingingCharacter? _character = SingingCharacter.avengers;

  void _gotoResultScreen(){

    Customer c= Customer(txtName.text, txtEmail.text, int.parse(txtQuantity.text));

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ResultPage(
            title:"Result Screen",
            content:"Congratulation! You've reached this page",
            customer: c,)
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Name'),
            TextField(
              controller: txtName,
            ),
            Text('Email'),
            TextField(
              controller: txtEmail,
            ),

            Text('Choose a movie:'),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('AVENGERS(RM20)'),
              leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                value: SingingCharacter.avengers,
                groupValue: _character,
                onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _character = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('BATMAN(RM10)'),
              leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                  value: SingingCharacter.batman,
                  groupValue: _character,
                  onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _character = value;
                    });
                  }
              ),
            ),

            ListTile(
              title: const Text('KIMETSU NO YAIBA(RM12)'),
              leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                  value: SingingCharacter.kimetsu,
                  groupValue: _character,
                  onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _character = value;
                    });
                  }
              ),
            ),

            Text('quantity'),
            TextField(
              controller: txtQuantity,
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              onPressed:_gotoResultScreen,
              //do something
              child: new Text('Calculate'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**result.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'customer.dart';

class ResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultPage({Key? key, required this.title, required this.content, required this.customer}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String content;
  final Customer customer;

  @override
  State<ResultPage> createState() => _ResultPageState();
}

class _ResultPageState extends State<ResultPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(widget.content,),
            Text("Name:" + widget.customer.name),
            Text("Email: " + widget.customer.email),
            Text("Quantity:" + widget.customer.quantity.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**customer.dart**

```
  class Customer {
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final int quantity;



  const Customer(this.name, this.email, this.quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to the solution above.
**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'calculate.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'eTicket'),
    );
  }
}

enum ticketName {Avengers,Batman,Kimetsu}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final TextEditingController _name = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _email = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _quantity = new TextEditingController();

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name = "";
  String email =  "";
  String quantity = "";
  String movieName = "";
  String ticketPrice = "";


  ticketName? _movieName = ticketName.Avengers;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric (
              horizontal: 20,),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

              children: <Widget>[
                const Text('Name',textAlign: TextAlign.left),

                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                ),

                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if(value!.isEmpty ){
                      return 'Please Enter Your Name';
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value){
                    name = value!;
                  },
                  controller: _name,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: '',
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity (0.2),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular (10))),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),

                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                ),

                const Text('Email',textAlign: TextAlign.left),

                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                ),

                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if(value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@') || !value.contains('.com'))
                    {
                      return 'Email is Invalid';
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value){
                    email = value!;
                  },
                  controller: _email,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: '',
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity (0.2),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular (10))),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),

                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                ),


                //add radio button here
                const Text("Choose a Movie: "),

                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                ),

                Row(children: [

                  Radio(

                    value: ticketName.Avengers,
                    groupValue: _movieName,
                    onChanged: (ticketName?value){
                      setState(() {
                        _movieName = value;
                        movieName = 'Avengers (RM 20.00)';
                        ticketPrice = '20';
                      });
                    },

                  ),
                  const SizedBox (width: 5.0,),
                  const Text("Avengers (RM 20.00)"),
                ],),
                Row(children: [
                  //add radio button here
                  Radio(
                    value: ticketName.Batman,
                    groupValue: _movieName,
                    onChanged: (ticketName? value){
                      setState(() {
                        _movieName = value;
                        movieName = 'Batman (RM 10.00) ';
                        ticketPrice = '10';
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox (width: 5.0,),
                  const Text("Batman (RM 10.00)"),
                ],),
                Row(children: [
                  //add radio button here
                  Radio(
                    value: ticketName.Kimetsu,
                    groupValue: _movieName,
                    onChanged: (ticketName? value){
                      setState(() {
                        _movieName = value;
                        movieName = 'Kimetsu No Yaiba (RM 12.00) ';
                        ticketPrice = '12';
                      });
                    },

                  ),
                  const SizedBox (width: 5.0,),
                  const Text("Kimetsu No Yaiba (RM 12.00)"),
                ],),


                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                ),

                const Text('Quantity',textAlign: TextAlign.left),

                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                ),

                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if(value!.isEmpty || value.length < 0){
                      return 'Please Enter the Correct Quantity';
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value){
                    var quantity = int.parse(value!);
                  },
                  controller: _quantity,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Quantity',
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity (0.2),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular (10))),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),

                const Padding (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                ),

                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    final isValid = formKey.currentState?.validate();
                    if(isValid!=null) {
                      formKey.currentState!.save();
                      Navigator.push(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => calculatePrice(name: _name.text, movieName: movieName, ticketPrice: ticketPrice, email: _email.text, quantity: _quantity.text)));
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Calculate'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**calculate.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class calculatePrice extends StatelessWidget {

  late String name, email, movieName, ticketPrice, quantity;


  calculatePrice({required this.name, required this.email, required this.quantity, required this.movieName, required this.ticketPrice});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("eTicket"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric (
              horizontal: 20,),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Name : $name'),
                const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
                Text('Email $email'),
                const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
                Text('Movie : $movieName'),
                const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
                Text('Quantity $quantity'),
                const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
                Text('Total Price : ${int.parse(quantity) * int.parse(ticketPrice) }'),
                const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),),

                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  const MyApp()));
                  },
                  child: const Text('Back'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<String, int>` to store the movie name and its price. Then create the `List<Map<String, int>>` and use the `.map()` function on this list to covert the list into `listTile`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass necessary arguments to result page. You passed Customer, that is ok. But movie info is missing. For example:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ResultPage(
        title:"Result Screen",
        content:"Congratulation! You've reached this page",
        customer: c,
        movieName: ...,
        price: ...,
      )
  ),
);
```

And of course you should edit Result page accordingly.

After go to result page. Use price data and multiply quantity. This is gonna be final price.

However, this is not a good approach, Instead of using this kind of solutions, I recommend create a Movie class like Customer. Also quantity info should not be a field of Customer, it should be field of Movie class.

Comment: ouh i understand, thank you so much . i will try this method by implement a new class

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the price like this.

Let's say your _character value is SingingCharacter.avengers

```
int price = getPriceFromCharacter(_character) * int.parse(txtQuantity.text);

getPriceFromCharacter(SingingCharacter? character) {
 switch(character) { 
   case SingingCharacter.avengers: { 
     return 20;
   } 
   case SingingCharacter.batman: { 
     return 10;
   } 
   case SingingCharacter.kimetsu: { 
     return 12;
   } 
  } 
}
void _gotoResultScreen(){
  int price = getPriceFromCharacter(_character) * int.parse(txtQuantity.text);
  Customer c= Customer(txtName.text, txtEmail.text, int.parse(txtQuantity.text));

  Navigator.push(
   context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ResultPage(
        title:"Result Screen",
        content:"Congratulation! You've reached this page",
        customer: c,)
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: where should i put this code ? is it inside class _ResultPageState?

Comment: int price = getPriceFromCharacter(_character) * int.parse(txtQuantity.text);
put this line in your _gotoResultScreen function. I've edited my answer check that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer based on the above code. Thank you for the suggestion and helps from the others.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'result.dart';
import 'customer.dart';
import 'movie.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'e-Ticket',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Movie e-Ticket'),
    );
  }
}

enum SingingCharacter { avengers, batman, kimetsu }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final txtName = TextEditingController();
  final txtEmail = TextEditingController();
  final txtQuantity = TextEditingController();
  SingingCharacter? _character = SingingCharacter.avengers;

  getPriceFromCharacter(SingingCharacter? character, int quantity) {
    switch (character) {
      case SingingCharacter.avengers:
        {
          return 20 * quantity;
        }
      case SingingCharacter.batman:
        {
          return 10 * quantity;
        }
      case SingingCharacter.kimetsu:
        {
          return 12 * quantity;
        }
    }
  }

  getMovieName(SingingCharacter? character) {
    switch (character) {
      case SingingCharacter.avengers:
        {
          return "Avengers";
        }
      case SingingCharacter.batman:
        {
          return "Batman";
        }
      case SingingCharacter.kimetsu:
        {
          return "Kimetsu";
        }
    }
  }

  // this to go to result screen and show the result
  void _gotoResultScreen() {
    int price = getPriceFromCharacter(_character, int.parse(txtQuantity.text));
    String movieName = getMovieName(_character);
    Customer c = Customer(txtName.text, txtEmail.text);
    Movie m = Movie(int.parse(txtQuantity.text), price, movieName);

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ResultPage(
            title: "Total Price",
            content: "Here is your details",
            customer: c,
            movie: m,
          )),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Name', textAlign: TextAlign.left),


            TextField(
              controller: txtName,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '',
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none
                )
              ),
            ),
            const Text('Email'),
            TextField(
              controller: txtEmail,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: '',
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide.none
            ),)
            ),

            // This is for radio button in list tile
            const Text('Choose a movie:'),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('AVENGERS(RM20)'),
              leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                value: SingingCharacter.avengers,
                groupValue: _character,
                onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _character = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),

            ListTile(
              title: const Text('BATMAN(RM10)'),
              leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                  value: SingingCharacter.batman,
                  groupValue: _character,
                  onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _character = value;
                    });
                  }),
            ),

            ListTile(
              title: const Text('KIMETSU NO YAIBA(RM12)'),
              leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                  value: SingingCharacter.kimetsu,
                  groupValue: _character,
                  onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _character = value;
                    });
                  }),
            ),

            // Input Quantity of the movie
            const Text('quantity'),
            TextField(
              controller: txtQuantity,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '',
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                )
              ),
            ),

            // When user click calculate Button
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _gotoResultScreen,
              child: const Text('Calculate'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**movie.dart**

```
class Movie {
  final int quantity;
  final int totalPrice;
  final String movieName;

  const Movie( this.quantity,this.totalPrice,this.movieName);
}
```

**result.dart**

```
import 'package:e_tickets/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'customer.dart';
import 'movie.dart';

class ResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultPage({Key? key, required this.title, required this.content, required this.customer, required this.movie}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String content;
  final Customer customer;
  final Movie movie;

  @override
  State<ResultPage> createState() => _ResultPageState();
}

class _ResultPageState extends State<ResultPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

          children: <Widget>[
            Text(widget.content,),
            const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
            Text("Name: " + widget.customer.name),
            const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
            Text("Email: " + widget.customer.email),
            const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
            Text("Quantity: " + widget.movie.quantity.toString()),
            const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
            Text("Movie Name: " + widget.movie.movieName),
            const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),
            Text("Total Price: RM" + widget.movie.totalPrice.toString()),
            const Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),),

            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  const MyApp()));
              },
              child: const Text('Back'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**customer.dart**

```
class Customer {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  const Customer(this.name, this.email);
}
```